# Get unique rows by checking column values sql

Tags: sql, sybase

I am very new to SQL so please excuse if you find the question silly.

**Table**

```
+--------------------+
id   state   isPresent
+--------------------+
id1    1      N
id2    2      N
id2    2      Y
id3    3      N
id4    4      N
id4    4      Y
id5    2      N
id5    2      Y
```

I need to get all the unidue ids where isPresent = N and isPresent = Y for a particular state.

For example,
if passed 2 (state) as a parameter to query, we should get result as id2 and id5 since isPresent = "N" and "Y" for that state.

Similary, if we pass 4, we should only get id4

using Sybase

Answer (score 0):

Try using inner join as below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(id)
FROM table t1 INNER JOIN table t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
AND t1.isPresent != t2.isPresent
WHERE state = 2
```

We are doing inner join on the table using id field being same and `isPresent` field holding on one as Y and other as N. I've hard coded state as 2, but you can parameterize it and use it in prepared statement programattically to pass it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple `WHERE` clause with `DISTINCT` does what you explained.

You need lines 11 - 14.

```
SQL> with test (id, state, ispresent) as
  2    (select 'id1', 1, 'N' from dual union all
  3     select 'id2', 2, 'N' from dual union all
  4     select 'id2', 2, 'Y' from dual union all
  5     select 'id3', 3, 'N' from dual union all
  6     select 'id4', 4, 'N' from dual union all
  7     select 'id4', 4, 'Y' from dual union all
  8     select 'id5', 2, 'N' from dual union all
  9     select 'id5', 2, 'Y' from dual
 10    )
 11  select distinct id
 12  from test
 13  where ispresent = 'N'
 14    and state = &par_id;
Enter value for par_id:   2

ID
---
id2
id5

SQL> /
Enter value for par_id: 4

ID
---
id4

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanna return a distinct `id`, provided that it has both cases (`N` and `Y`) at the same time for `isPresent` column. So, consider using the following SQL statement with `exists` operator by changing the parameters (now it's `2`) :

```
with tab(id, state, isPresent) as
(
 select 'id1', 1, 'N'  union all
 select 'id2', 2, 'N'  union all
 select 'id2', 2, 'Y'  union all
 select 'id3', 3, 'N'  union all
 select 'id4', 4, 'N'  union all
 select 'id4', 4, 'Y'  union all
 select 'id5', 2, 'N'  union all
 select 'id5', 2, 'Y' 
)
select distinct id 
  from tab t1
 where exists ( select 1 
                  from tab t2 
                 where t2.state = t1.state 
                   and t2.isPresent in ('N','Y') -- this line might be commented out, if it's certain that there're only two cases "N" and "Y"
                 group by t2.state
                 having count(distinct t2.isPresent) = 2
               )  
   and t1.state = 2 -- try other values also such as 1, 3, 4
```

For the values `1` and `3` no row will be returned, while for `2` and `4` returns at least one row.

<kbd>[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/OOBE73216)</kbd>